# Does "whereabouts" function as a singular or plural noun?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

> His whereabouts is unknown

vs

> His whereabouts are unknown

Which is correct, or is this simply a matter of preference?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Wiktionary [marks](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/whereabouts#Noun) *whereabouts* as [*plurale tantum*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurale_tantum). Merriam-Webster [says](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whereabouts?show=2&t=1291197671) that it's a "noun plural but singular or plural in construction". The Collins English Dictionary says that it is "functioning as singular or plural", and the American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language says that it is "used with a singular or plural verb". The [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) has 23 cites for "whereabouts are unknown", but only 3 cites for "whereabouts is unknown". Finally, Google returns 1.1M results for "whereabouts are unknown" vs 191k results for "whereabouts is unknown". So, neither of the forms is unheard of, but "whereabouts are unknown" is preferred by a rather significant margin.

Comment: For some reason, the "s" on the end of the word always makes me read it as plural and so I lean towards the use of "are" rather than "is". I have heard the use of "is" in this context before, and can understand it when taking the word "whereabouts" to mean "current location", however it just does not feel correct to me.

Comment: RegDwight's references above spell it right out: either way is acceptable.  Phrases "...her whereabouts is unknown..." and "...her whereabouts are unknown..." are equally correct.

Comment: If you're trying to sound native I'd always treat whereabouts as a plural. "His whereabouts **is** unknown" sounds weird.

Answer (score 2):

Since @RegDwight has already provided an answer with strict supporting background information, let me answer this question from a conversational perspective.

I would think of a person's *whereabouts* as ***places*** *where he has been*. Note my emphasis on ***places***. That's plural. So,

> His whereabouts are unknown.

The context here would be that we do not know the ***places*** he has been going to.

Comment: The plural does not have that implication for me.

Comment: "I am going to Tubbercurry."  "Whereabouts is that?"

Comment: @Remou : I don't believe that's a good example for "whereabouts", but rather a poorly formed question ... using it more in a slang context. "About where is that?" would be a more proper way to write it. The word "whereabouts" that is being discussed is a noun.

Comment: @Will I disagree and cite http://www.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/whereabouts.html, for one, I can add more.

Comment: @Remou : Your link, I believe, answers the original question. My point in my comment was that "Whereabouts is 'x'?" is not the same as "X's whereabouts is/are unknown". In question form, as you used it, I believe it is more of a slang manner of asking "Where is 'x'?" or "Approximately where is 'x'?"

Comment: I have to disagree with this context. I'd think of *whereabouts* as a person's spatial position at that time.

Comment: @Remou: I think that "Whereabouts is that?" is more colloquial and less grammatically correct. At least according to my experience.

Comment: This answer is spot on. Change the sentence to: "his location" and "is" then becomes the correct word to use.

Comment: @Will: I'm having trouble understanding why 'whereabouts' as one part of speech is slang, but as another it's, well, I guess, not slang.

Answer (score 1):

The Associated Press 2011 Stylebook records "whereabouts" to take a singular verb.

"His whereabouts is a mystery."

While I believe it to sound and appear incorrect, the AP is the horse's mouth.

Answer (score 0):

Considered from the standpoint of sense alone, **the singular seems more correct** to me, since the **meaning** of the word is something like “**location**.” **The New York Times stylebook** has long required that “**whereabouts**” be treated as **singular**.

**But** one’s ear sometimes disagrees. And **Bryan A. Garner notes** in his **Dictionary of Modern American Usage** that the **plural verb is 10 times as common as the singular** in printed sources. So I guess you could conclude that the **plural verb is preferred by most writers**.